# issues two different insert query in one form in codeginter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I tried to one form insert to different one table name is **horses** and other is table name is **filename_img** query means I have different fields in one table and other I want to insert image to other table but my one form to insert fields and images  this is my model and please confirm my query what i am going wrong because show the query show for query  error thanks advances

**Model**

```
function horses_insert($data){
                    $postcode = addslashes($data['postcode']);
                    $height = addslashes($data['height']);
                    $breed_id = addslashes($data['breed_id']);
                    $colour_id = addslashes($data['colour_id']);
                    $age = addslashes($data['age']);
                    $gender = addslashes($data['gender']);
                    $name = addslashes($data['name']);
                    $price = addslashes($data['price']);
                    $description = addslashes($data['description']);
                    // $image = addslashes($data['image']);
                    $status = addslashes($data['status']);
                    $price_currency = addslashes($data['price_currency']);
                    $height_unit = addslashes($data['height_unit']);
                    $is_urgent = addslashes($data['is_urgent']);
                    $is_featured = addslashes($data['is_featured']);
                    $is_spotlight = addslashes($data['is_spotlight']);
                    $is_sale = addslashes($data['is_sale']);
                    if($is_urgent=="on"){
                        $is_urgent="1";
                    }else{
                        $is_urgent="0";
                    }

                    if($is_featured=="on"){
                        $is_featured="1";
                    }else{
                        $is_featured="0";
                    }

                    if($is_spotlight=="on"){
                        $is_spotlight="1";
                    }else{
                        $is_spotlight="0";
                    }

                    if($is_sale=="on"){
                        $is_sale="1";
                    }else{
                        $is_sale="0";
                    }




                    $result= $this->db->query("INSERT INTO horses (postcode,height,breed_id,colour_id,age,gender,name,price, description,is_urgent,is_featured,is_spotlight,is_sale,status,price_currency,height_unit) VALUES ('$postcode','$height','$breed_id','$colour_id','$age','$gender','$name','$price','$description','$is_urgent','$is_featured','$is_spotlight','$is_sale','$status','$price_currency','$height_unit')");
                    $id=$this->db->insert_id();

                    //return $id;
                    if ($result) {
            $userfile = addslashes($data['userfile']);

                        $query= $this->db->query("INSERT INTO filename_img (userfile,$id) VALUES ('$userfile','')");
                        $id=$this->db->insert_id();
                        return $id;
                    }

            }
```

Comment: Could you show the error here?

Comment: A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '51) VALUES ('h33.jpg','')' at line 1

INSERT INTO filename_img (userfile,51) VALUES ('h33.jpg','')

Filename: models/admin/Horse.php

Line Number: 96

Comment: INSERT INTO filename_img (userfile,51) VALUES ('h33.jpg','') , instead of 51 there should be field name (id) not number in your query

Comment: @abrar i am new in codeginter i dont how i pas the id last id in insert query

Comment: share your filename_img table fields here.

Comment: @abrar plz brother correct this query $query= $this->db->query("INSERT INTO filename_img (userfile,$id) VALUES ('$userfile','')");
                        $id=$this->db->insert_id();

Comment: I will correct this if you show me the filename_img table fields names here.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
$userfile = addslashes($data['userfile']); 

$commaSeprartedFilesName = implode(",",$userfile);

$query= $this->db->query("INSERT INTO filename_img (userfile,id) VALUES ('$commaSeprartedFilesName',$id)");

$id=$this->db->insert_id();

return $id;
```

UserFile should be array in html like

Comment: brother the query is work perfectly thanks but one issuse is that i want multipe image in one id but i select multiple image they insert multiple record as for images like i select two image so they insert to same recod but i not want to insert my field is repet insert

Comment: so you want to add the images comma separated right?

Comment: brother its repeat the image id and not insert images

Comment: $userfile = addslashes($data['userfile']); 

$commaSeprartedFilesName = implode(",",$userfile);

$query= $this->db->query("INSERT INTO filename_img (userfile,id) VALUES ('$commaSeprartedFilesName',$id)");

$id=$this->db->insert_id();

return $id; this query not insert the image and repeat the id of select image

Comment: brother not insert the image when i debug there is not coming in comma sepreated file name  when i use this code  $completeFileName = implode(',',(array)$userfile);   
   //  echo $completeFileName;
   // print_r($completeFileName); exit();
   return $this->db->query("INSERT INTO filename_img (userfile) VALUES ('$completeFileName')"); they insert image but not in image row they are insert three different id

Comment: any solution brother